# How to position 2nd-child element against coordinate space of a wrapper element

Tags: html, css

I have a very specific problem that although can easily be solved by changing the HTML or using negative margins/absolute positioning, in this occasion neither are possible.

In a nutshell, I need the "2nd-child" element which is larger than the "1st-child" element to be positioned against the coordinate space of the "wrapper".  This may not be possible but being able to do so would greatly decrease the complexity required in some javascript calculations we need to perform.

Under normal circumstances we would set the "1st-child" to position relative or absolute in order to position the "2nd-child" against the coordinate space of its parent.  I need to reverse this behaviour.  Therefore I have tried static positioning on the "1st-child" naively assuming that the "2nd child" would be positioned against the "wrapper".  (left:0; top:0; would result in the "2nd child" being positioned into the top left corner of the wrapper).  While this positions the elements correctly it removes the required clipping set on the "1st-child" and displays the whole of "2nd-child".

**So to summarise**.  How can I position the "2nd-child" element against the coordinate space of the "wrapper" element so that `top:0; left:0;` result in the "2nd child" being pushed into the top left corner despite it being a child the "1st-child" element **while still maintaining the 'clipping' behaviour of `overflow:hidden;`** which is set on "1st-child".

**DISCLAIMER:**

for the sake of readibility in the code below I have used ID's which start with numbers.  This cannot be done in real code but makes referring to the elements far easier in this question.

[image]

HTML:

```
   <div id="wrapper">
          <div id="1st-child">
              <div id="2nd-child">
              </div>
          </div>
    <div>
```

CSS :

```
   #wrapper {
       position:fixed;
       width:1000px;
       height:1000px;
       top:0;
       left:0;
    }

   #1st-child {
       margin-left : 200px;
       margin-top : 200px;
       width: 300px;
       height: 200px;
       position:static;
       overflow: hidden;
   }

   #2nd-child {
       position:absolute;
       top:0;
       left:0;
       width:750px;
       height:600px;
   }
```

Comment: Is it a typo that `2nd-child` isn't closed?

Comment: So, you want `2nd-child` to be in the top left corner of `wrapper`? In your screenshot, isn't that the same as top left corner of `1st-child`? Also, does `wrapper` have to be `position: fixed`

Comment: @crush No, 1st-child is the blue rectangle in the middle.  And wrapper can be either fixed or absolute, but ideally fixed.  I should also mention that the code above does work but it removes the ability to essentially clip the 2nd-child by using overflow:hidden;  on 1st-child, which i need.  I omitted this from my original question.  I will edit it now.

Comment: Are you trying to create a masking effect?

Comment: Why not just make `2nd-child` a child of `wrapper` instead of `1st-child`, and just set the z-index higher?

Comment: Essentially yes.   There are far easier ways to do this I know.  However we need one which works with a rotated portal element.  Being able to do this and simply reverse the rotation on "2nd-child" would greatly simply the math required to set the correct transform origin on 2nd-child

Comment: I think he wants to make `1st-child` a clipping mask of `2nd-child`.

Comment: @Blazemonger because then 2nd-child will not be clipped by overflow:hidden; on 1st-child

Comment: I think you'll have to actually do the math, then. CSS positioning only works relative to the closest positioned parent; there's no way to tell it to position relative to a different parent using pure CSS.

Comment: Why don't you set `position: relative;` to the `wrapper` and then position the `2nd-child` with `position: absolute; top: Xpx; left:Xpx;` ?

Comment: @Blazemonger indeed.  However by using position:static on 1st-child I actually get the correct positioning behaviour.  However when doing so this element also loses its masking ability by rendering overflow:hidden useless.  This is something I did not expect.

Comment: Why does it need to be `position: static` exactly?

Comment: By setting position:static (or omitting the position altogether so that it defaults to static) 2nd-child then inherits the coordinate space of "wrapper" allowing top:0;left:0 to set 2nd-child into the top left corner of wrapper

Answer (score 0):

`id` attributes can't start with a digit.  Renaming your `id` attributes and changing the selectors that reference them results in a page that has the layout you want.

[Example on CodePen](http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/KGwjr)

Comment: IDs *can* start with a digit in HTML5 and in most browsers that only understand HTML4, even though the w3c spec says otherwise.

Comment: @Blazemonger: He's referring to CSS, and [he's completely right.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters)

Comment: Regardless, this was to easily refer to the elements within the scope of this question.  This is not actual code.  I will now add a disclaimer for any people new to coding.  I don't see how this is an answer however?

Comment: @gordyr, this is the difference between non-working code and working code that does what you want in the latest version of Safari.

Comment: Only problem I see is that overflow: hidden isn't hiding `2nd-child` div when it is applied.

Comment: And please don't post code that isn't representative of what you are using, all it does is waste people's time.

Comment: @Jim It does not.  1st-child still does not mask 2nd-child in safari or any other browser whatever I name the ID's.  Regarding wasting peoples time, would you not agree that posting a complaint about a question as an actual "answer" is doing the same?

Comment: From reading back I can see this answer was not intended as a complaint, instead it was a misunderstanding of the question.  Probably down to me articulating it poorly.  My apologies.

Comment: @gordyr, I just took a look at your edit history for this question to confirm.  I correctly answered your original question.  You then edited it to add further requirements for a different bug.  You should have marked it as correct then opened a new question.

Comment: @Jim except that positioning was never the problem I had,  It was purely the fact that when positioned used the method above, there is no clipping.  My fault for omitting it from the question originally.  But I was hoping for another method of positioning in this manner so that overflow:hidden still works

Comment: Your problem was no clipping yet you forgot to mention it in the question entirely?

Comment: No the problem was that when positioning in the manner described there is no clipping.  Therefore I was looking for a different positioning method in order to achieve the same thing. If this was not the case I would not have mistaken your question as a complaint and seen it as an answer as it was intended. Seriously, can we please drop this now, I stupidly put numbers first in my example code... Please just let it lie, this is not helping anyone.

Comment: *"No the problem was that when positioning in the manner described there is no clipping"*  Look, everybody can see your original question just by looking at the revision history.  You said: *"I have tried static positioning on the "1st-child" naively assuming that the "2nd child" would be positioned against the "wrapper" [...] Unfortunately this does not seem to be the case."*  That was the original question.  You tried to position it in this way, but it didn't position in the way you expected.

Comment: I don't know why you are so keen to pretend your original question was about clipping, but it clearly wasn't.  I'll stop pointing out that you are saying untrue things as soon as you stop saying them.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question?

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <div id="child1">
         <div id="child2">
             Hello
         </div>
     </div>
<div>
<style>
   #wrapper {
       width:600px;
       height:300px;
       background-color: pink;
       overflow: hidden;
    }

   div#child1 {
       margin-left: 100px;
       margin-top: 50px;
       width: 200px;
       height: 150px;
       border: 1px solid green;
   }

   div#child2 {
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       width: 200px;
       height: 200px;
       border: 1px solid red;
   }
</style>
```

I changed id's (they can't start with a number), and sizes (for debugging purposes)

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/5aL9s/

Comment: This is the same as my answer.  He's added further requirements now.

Comment: Nope as child1 (which i should have just named my bloody div's in the first place to avoid the confusion with Jim) still does not clip child2.  Thanks you for the comprehensive attempt however

Comment: @gordyr I haven't saw the clipping requirement. I'm not sure that this can be done with your scenario.

Comment: @MarceloPascual Thanks,  It's my fault for not correctly writing the question the first time round.  I think you're right.  Javascript it will have to be.  Thanks for your answer anyway :)

Comment: @Jim you're right, I haven't saw your answer before I posted mine. I upvoted yours ;)

Answer (score -2):

```
#2nd-child {
   position:absolute;
   top:-200px;
   left:-200px;
   width:750px;
   height:600px;
}
```

Comment: Please note that there's no "javascript" tag for this question.

Comment: Thanks Don, but I cannot use javascript for this.  Once the elements are rotated these simple calculated become useless.  Hence the reason I am trying to do this part with pure css.